# C# 4 default parameter values: How to assign a default DateTime/object value?

Tags: c#, default-parameters

If DateTime is an object and default C# parameters can only be assigned compile-time constants, how do you provide default values for objects like DateTime?

I am trying to initialize values in a POCO with a constructor, using named parameters with default values.

Comment: Call an overloaded method that sets the parameter: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3031309/492

Answer (score 190, accepted):

`DateTime` cannot be used as a constant but you could make it a nullable type (`DateTime?`) instead.

Give the `DateTime?` a default value of `null`, and if it is set to `null` at the start of your function, then you can initialize it to any value you want.

```
static void test(DateTime? dt = null)
{
    if (dt == null)
    {
        dt = new DateTime(1981, 03, 01);
    }

    //...
}
```

You can call it with a named parameter like this:

```
test(dt: new DateTime(2010, 03, 01));
```

And with the default parameter like this:

```
test();
```

Comment: What about DateTime.MinValue?

Comment: @Dr.Zim: No it's readonly but not constant.

Comment: And why wouldn't DateTime.MinValue be a compiler-time constant?

Comment: @Dr. Zim: because DateTime can't be declared as const.  I don't know why that's the way it is.

Comment: you can use: `DateTime dt = default(DatetTime)`

Comment: if (!dt.HasValue) startDate = new DateTime(2010, 03, 01);

Answer (score 60):

The only way you can do this directly is to use the value `default(DateTime)`, which is compile-time constant. Or you can work around that by using `DateTime?` and setting the default value to `null`.

See also [this related question about `TimeSpan`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168798/c-4-0-can-i-use-a-timespan-as-an-optional-parameter-with-a-default-value).

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Sometimes using DateTime? is messier.

Comment: thanks.. default or minvalue by @Dr. Zim does the trick for me. but default is what i like. saved me from posting another question! :)

Answer (score 8):

new DateTime() also equals DateTime.MinValue

You could a create a default parameter like so.

```
void test(DateTime dt = new DateTime())
{
//...
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work, you cannot use functions in a default parameter.

Comment: @Kirbinator it works try it.

Comment: I can't believe it compiles when I do this. I have yet to see, though, if it will be fine at runtime.

Comment: Since it is DateTime is struct it will work.

Answer (score 4):

Unlike VB, C# doesn't support date literals. And since optional parameters look like this in IL, you can't fake it with attributes.

```
.method private hidebysig static void foo([opt] int32 x) cil managed
{
    .param [1] = int32(5)
    .maxstack 8
    L_0000: nop 
    L_0001: ret 
}



.method //this is a new method
private hidebysig static //it is private, ???, and static
void foo  //it returns nothing (void) and is named Foo
([opt] int32 x) //it has one parameter, which is optional, of type int32

.param [1] = int32(5) //give the first param a default value of 5
```

Comment: Can you please explain this code?

Comment: ok thank you :) Date time also we can give the same manner like .param [1] = DateTime(5) ?

Answer (score -1):

```
private System.String _Date= "01/01/1900";
public virtual System.String Date
{
   get { return _Date; }
   set { _Date= value; }
}
```

We can assign value to a label like given below,

```
lblDate.Text = Date;
```

Also we can get the value,

```
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(label1.Text);
```

Comment: Cannot be used as parameter still. Does not answer the question.

Answer (score -3):

you could use:

```
Datetime.MinValue
```

for initialization.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question as you can't set this as the default value as it's not a constant