# Set default value for DateTime in optional parameter

Tags: c#, datetime, default, optional-parameters

How can I set default value for DateTime in optional parameter?

```
public SomeClassInit(Guid docId, DateTime addedOn = DateTime.Now???)
{
    //Init codes here
}
```

Comment: This is not a duplicate Timespans work differently in c# than timespans. This is doable in c# with `DateTimeConstantAttribute` but timespans do not support this.

Answer (score 172, accepted):

There is a workaround for this, taking advantage of nullable types and the fact that `null` is a compile-time constant. (It's a bit of a hack though, and I'd suggest avoiding it unless you really can't.)

```
public void SomeClassInit(Guid docId, DateTime? addedOn = null)
{
    if (!addedOn.HasValue)
        addedOn = DateTime.Now;

    //Init codes here
}
```

In general, I'd prefer the standard overloading approach suggested in the other answers:

```
public SomeClassInit(Guid docId)
{
    SomeClassInit(docId, DateTime.Now);
}

public SomeClassInit(Guid docId, DateTime addedOn)
{
    //Init codes here
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand why optional params must be compile-time constants. The compiler could easily create the 2 methods you wrote from the one with the optional param...I usually prefer having one method with several optional params instead of several methods, it makes the code smaller and thus easier to read.

Comment: You can use coalesce here: `addedOn = addedOn ?? DateTime.Now`

Comment: Nullables can cause casting problems deep in your code, so I am not a fan.  I am becoming increasing disappointed in C#.  I mean, even VB.net has literal dates, such as: Optional addedOn As DateTime = #12:00:00 PM#

Comment: VS wouldnt compile with this code. Instead i used DateTime date = default(DateTime), and then checked to see if date==default(DateTime)

Answer (score 60):

I guess that you did not really want `addedOn = DateTime.Now` because that would suggest you never get any result as everything would be added before 'Now'. :)

A default `DateTime` can be set like this:

```
public void SomeClassInit(Guid docId, DateTime addedOn = default(DateTime))
```

---

**Update**
If you deal with SQL Server, do not forget that it doesn't accept default(DateTime) what is 1/1/0001. SQL Server's minimal DateTime is 1/1/1753 ([explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310569/what-is-the-significance-of-1-1-1753-in-sql-server)). SQL's DateTime2 accepts 1/1/0001, though.

Comment: Dont understand why this isnt marked as the answer, it allows for much easier working with datetime, since datetime? != datetime

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Comment: I'm just going to voice what others have said, this IS the correct answer. The others are basically just cheating the system.

Comment: I suppose this is gong to return a default value for datetime. what if someone wants the current datetime ?

Answer (score 30):

I'd slightly modify LukeH's solution as:

```
public void SomeClassInit(Guid docId, DateTime? addedOn = null)
{
    DateTime TargetDateTimeProperty = addedOn ?? DateTime.Now;
}
```

which is shorter and more readable, it seems.

Comment: It is not more readable but it allows me to access the .Year/.Month filelds.

Answer (score 8):

Don't use an optional parameter:

```
public SomeClassInit(Guid docId, DateTime addedOn)
{
    SomeClassInitCore(docId, addedOn);
}

public SomeClassInit(Guid docId)
{
    SomeClassInitCore(docId, null);
}

private SomeClassInitCore(Guid docId, DateTime? addedOn)
{
    // set default value
    if (addedOn.IsNull) addedOn = DateTime.Now;

    //Init codes here
}
```

Answer (score 6):

[.NET 4.0 does have optional parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx). ([google is also your friend](http://www.google.com.au/#hl=en&source=hp&q=optional+paramters+.net+4.0&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&fp=6754f67ee51d4c5b), here.)

EDIT (because of Anthony Pegram correct, comment)...

<strike>And yes, that is how you would do it.</strike>

But `DateTime.`*Now* (static property, on that class) is not know until *run-time*. As such, you can't use that as an optional *value*.

.NET 3.5 doesn't ... so then you would have to do what JS Bangs said...

```
public SomeClassInit(Guid docId) 
{ 
    return SomeClassInit(docId, DateTime.Now);
}

public SomeClassInit(Guid docId, DateTime addedOn = DateTime.Now???) 
{ 
    //Init codes here 
}
```

or even the null checking/null value parameter from munificent's answer.

Cheers Anthony.

Comment: The default value must be a compile time constant, so this is not going to work even in 4.0.

Comment: Confirmed Anothony. I'll re-edit my post. Cheers.

Comment: This Shoud Be The Accepted Answer (TSBTAA). This is the only answer that actually and clearly explains why it's not possible to use common `DateTime` "values" for optional argument.

Answer (score 2):

C# doesn't have optional parameters in this sense. If you want to make `addedOn` optional, you should write an overload that doesn't require that parameter, and passes `DateTime.Now` to the two-argument version.

Comment: er.. sure abot that JS Bangs? for framework version .NET 3.5 and below, you are correct. otherwise, 4.0 and above, it is supported.

Comment: @Pure.Krome, default values for optional parameters must be compile time constants. So this is *not* supported. (This answer could be worded better, however.)

Comment: i too misunderstood the wording. soz JS.