# How create default parameters for methods c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, optional-parameters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# 4.0: Can I use a TimeSpan as an optional parameter with a default value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168798/c-4-0-can-i-use-a-timespan-as-an-optional-parameter-with-a-default-value)

Ok I know how to create default parameters for some of the variables. for example I can create default parameters as:

```
public void someMethod(int x = 1, double y = 2)
{
      //....      
}
```

ok but let's say that my method requires an object of type TimeSpan. when I try:

```
public void someMethod(TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)){

}
```

I get the error:

> Default parameter value for 't' must be a compile time constant

as a result I tried creating a constant of type TimeSpan as:

```
private const TimeSpan defaultVal = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);

public void someMethod(TimeSpan t = defaultVal)
{

}
```

and this too gives me an error. How can I solve this?